# Off-Line Java API Documentation in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, offline, java

Is there an integration of any other off line way to get the Java API docs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have no internet connection on your development machine, or if you want to stop the Web traffic for accessing the documentation, you can store the documentation on your local hard drive.

1. Start your favorite Web browser and navigate to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html#docs
2. Find your desired documentation, accept the license agreement, and then click the link displayed under the `Download` header.
3. In Eclipse, open the `Window` menu, then select `Preferences`.
4. In the search bar, type `jre`, and then click `Installed JREs`.
5. Select the one named `java`, or another term like `jre1.8.0_181`.

   - Its type must be `Standard VM`.
6. Click the `Edit` button.
7. In the `JRE system libraries` section, select the library ending with `rt.jar`, and click the `Javadoc Location...` button.
8. Mark the `Javadoc in archive` radio button.
9. In the `Archive path` field, enter or `Browse` for your full documentation path (e.g. `/home/docs/jdk-8u181-doc.zip`).
10. In the `Path within archive` field, enter or `Browse` for the location of the `api/index.html` file (e.g. `docs/api`).
11. Click the `Validate` button to ensure everything is set correctly.
12. Click the `OK` button, then the `Finish` button, and finally the `Apply & Close` button. Your documentation is now linked to the file you specified.

Comment: Couldn't ask for a better solution, Thanks a lot!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am using java 14. Please find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick contribution:
Instead of selecting 7 "Javadoc in archive", I changed the javadoc location path (URL) to my directory, where I have unzipped my doc. 
Hope its help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Java 8):

1. Go to your JDK installation. (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66` for me).
2. Unzip the `src.zip` file (becomes `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\src\` for me).
3. In the Eclipse editor window: `CTRL + Click` on a `java.lang` library class. (something like `String`).
4. Eclipse will complain `Source not found` and tell you that you don't have the source.
5. Click `Attach source` -> `External Location` -> `External Folder`.
6. Find your source folder (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\src\` for me).
7. Click `OK` -> `OK`.
8. Enjoy.