# Documentation offline searchable....Java, Javascript, JQuery, Angular...etc.

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, documentation

Is there a way to get Documentation offline and searchable?  For example for Java I have done this to get Java doc offline.

[Off-Line Java API Documentation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664007/off-line-java-api-documentation-in-eclipse)

But is there a way that I can make this searchable?  Because I am just starting so when I am to look for a Java Map for example.  I don't know if its under java.lang or java.util...etc  So it makes looking for specific doc extremely hard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging

I found this https://zealdocs.org/  and https://kapeli.com/dash

The beauty of this is this is not only for java but for other languages such as javascript, angularjs, swift...etc

=D  Happy coding